# modifying the POST data sent to a limited PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I am using a CMS-like system, phpBMS, which defines certain fields and ways to generate a form.

[Here](http://www.phpbms.org/browser/trunk/phpbms/modules/sample/sampletable_addedit.php) is the sample form provided. It is possible to include javascript files and incorporate script into the form as well.

I would like to know if it is possible, within the confines of the framework I am working with, to send additional data back via POST, and to make use of it in the php form.

Going by the example there does not seem to be anywhere I could read in the new POST data and make use of it.

Ideally, I would like to modify how the POST data is treated when it comes back. However I am not sure if I can do that without modifying the code for the entire framework.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

edit:

If I use print_r(_POST);, this is the outputI get

Array ( [chooseguests] => :08490ea8-d654-1c91-cb82-00d44a4b093b [ds-chooseguests] => Holmes, Sherlock [chooseproducts] => 75c72a6a-83d9-11df-951a-fa9c1ec271f2 [ds-chooseproducts] => Corona [quantity] => 2 [type] => cash [receiptno] => 7 [createdby] => [creationdate] => [command] => save [modifiedby] => [cancelclick] => 0 [modifieddate] => [uuid] => :4402add3-b884-43e6-04ad-c76d92ee465b [id] => )

What I want to do is take the value of [ds-chooseguests], i.e. in this instance "Holmes, Sherlock" and split it into two parts, so i can insert holmes into a lastname field and sherlock into a firstname field.

I am unsure how to go about this without making modifications to the actual framework...

Comment: What have you tried? If you just insert another $theform->addField(..); shouldn't you see something with print_r($_POST)? If you add additional form fields client-side (with jQuery), they would appear too. Or what's exactly the method you want to "send additional data back via POST"?

Comment: Hi mario, I have only tried print_r($_POST) to see what is returned, and have no real idea how to do what I need to do. I have edited my question to show the output from _POST

Comment: Do you have complete control of the (php, I assume) page that is performing the handling? What happens to the data after you process it?

Is this the correct sequence of events: 1) phpbms generates the form. 2) User fills out and submits the form. 3) your php page processes the form. 4) ???

If 4) involves more action from the framework, it will usually require action on your part to make it have any meaning to pass your new fields onward.

Comment: @JGB146 that is essentially it. I have ways to add javascript to the form and such, but I don´t know that I can alter the basic behavior for just one form.

Answer (score 0):

Create new form fields using the framework code and set it from the server. Then those fields will get picked up in the form data that is sent back and you can process from php.